# Server over vpn in local network

Tags: networking, vpn, local, secure

In need to integrate a server which stands in a datacenter into a local network.The server should only be accessed over the local net not publicly.

The server is only accessible over ssh not physical. I think the best solution would be over vpn. I haven't dealt much which vpns so I wanted to ask if I am on the right track and how exactly that could work.

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear so asking how VPN would can't be answered - what services does the server provide and what router do you gave on your man (is can a VPN be added to it?)

Comment: its an application server, so a relatively high bandwidth is needed. Don't know wich router is on the spot, but wouldn't be a problem to exchange it. So the best solution would be a router with vpn to the server?

Comment: Again, your question is to vague to properly answer. (You say its only available via ssg, but then say its an app server - without defining how the apps are served). One typical model is to have a VPN client  on your router and connect to a VPN server on the VM. Then route traffic to the box across the VPN. Unfortunately this is fairly CPU intensive.  If "the apps are served" over an encrypted connection (like https) l, and if you have a static IP and dont need the extra security layet it is cheaper and simpler to just firewall the VM server to only respond to your IPs.